# Get Midnight of Local Timezone then convert to Epoch (UTC)

Tags: javascript

I am working with a date issue and would appreciate any suggestions as for some reason this is not making sense to me:

Esentially I have the user selecting a date with the input date method, this gives a simple date string with no time, I then attempt to convert this to a date object with:

```
let localDate = new Date(this.startDate);
```

I would expect the output to be in local time since usually new Date() will provide a local time object however the resulting object is midnight of the date specified but UTC.

My goal is to get midnight (local time zone) of the user selected date and then convert that to Epoch.  Currently when I try to use my code what I get is midnight of the selected date but in UTC time.

Comment: Are you sure `this.startDate` is a string? If so, can you please post an example value for it?

Comment: this.StartDate prints as: "2018-09-08"

Answer (score 1):

This is documented in the [Date MDN Page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) as follows:

> Support for ISO 8601 formats differs in that date-only strings (e.g.
>   "1970-01-01") are treated as UTC, not local.

I would suggest you save that date object in a variable and then manually set the hour to 0 for it. An example would be:

```
var d = new Date("2018-09-08");
d.setHours(0);
```

That way you set the hour to 00:00:00 and you also keep it as the local hour. The thing is that this issue is browser dependent. I've tested this on Safari and Chrome and it worked. The new Date is in local time, but not 00:00. For example, I am on GMT+3 and the hour new Date shows me is `03:00:00 GMT+0300`.

Even so, in Firefox this does not work. Firefox takes that as the 00:00 UTC. So you have some options here. You can get the timezone offset with `new Date().getTimezoneOffset();` Be careful that this method is error prone. You can take use the following to calculate the hour difference from local time to UTC `-(new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / 60)` and use this to specify the timezone in the date string.

This will soon get complicated and you can get into strange problems with dates in Javascript. So, the simple solution that should work on all browsers if you just need the date as the string is to use:

```
var d = new Date("2018-09-08");
d.toLocaleString();
```

Hope this helps you!